How to plot the mean of data points in matplotlib?
I am trying to plot a graph in Python. I have plotted the graph and the means are not at the right place. Could anyone point the mistake in the code?
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("PB1_MG_5.8.csv")

ax=sns.stripplot(data = data, x='Target', y='Value', edgecolor='black', 
            jitter=True, dodge=True, linewidth=1, hue="Condition", hue_order=['NoNS2','NS2'],  alpha = 0.3)

sns.despine()
ax.legend( ['-NS2','+NS2'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.7), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.,frameon=False, title='PB1')

plt.ylabel('log$2$(1600/length)')
a =plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')
ax.set_yscale('log', base=2)
ax.set_ylim(1,8)

for position, Target in enumerate(['200nt', '400nt', '800nt']):
    y = data[data.Condition == 'NoNS2'].Value.mean()
    plt.plot([position-0.325, position-0.075], [y, y], lw=4, c='k', zorder=9)
    y = data[data.Condition == 'NS2'].Value.mean()
    plt.plot([position+0.075, position+0.325], [y, y], lw=4, c='k', zorder=9)


I want the means for each group

The problem is that you're calculating the mean of all values for each condition and plotting that mean for all targets. Instead, you should be calculating and plotting the mean for each target within each condition:
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("PB!_MG_5.8.csv")
ax = sns.stripplot(data = data, x='Target', y='Value', edgecolor='black', jitter=True, dodge=True, linewidth=1, hue='Condition', hue_order=['NoNS2', 'NS2'], alpha = 0.3)
sns.despine()
ax.legend( ['-NS2', '+NS2'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 0.7), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.,frameon=False, title='PB1')
plt.ylabel('log$2$(1600/lenght)')
a =plt.xticks(rotation-45, ha='right')
ax.set_yscale('log', base=2)
ax.set_ylim(1,8)
for position, target in enumerate(['200nt', '400nt', '800nt']):
    y = data[(data.Condition == 'NoNS2') & (data.Target == target)].Value.mean()
    plt.plot([position-0.325, position-0.075], [y, y], lw=4, c='k', zorder=9)
    y = data[(data.Condition == 'NS2') & (data.Target == target)].Value.mean()
    plt.plot([position+0.075, position+0.325], [y, y], lw=4, c='k', zorder=9)

